# Emacs fonts rendered warped with glitches when scrolling

Tags: macos, emacs

I have a large/mature Emacs configuration (around 5 years old) which I use only occasionally. Mostly I used it with Linux, but now with OSX it's giving me problems.

On scroll, fonts look with the following glitch (warp effect):

[image]

What could be the issue?

Comment: I found a workaround: resize the window to any size and the issue will disappear.

Comment: What version of Emacs are use using?

Comment: 24.5 (http://emacsformacosx.com/ build)

Comment: Can you you give a simple step-by-step description on how to reproduce this, starting from "emacs -Q"?

Comment: I don't think so, unfortunately. Issue only happens with my (fairly large and unconventional) setup. The mentioned workaround will do.